# cpp-ffmpeg how to resolve deprecated warning?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, deprecation-warning

I am working with FFmpeg Lib, and I get a warning, my code as below:

```
if ( avformat_find_stream_info( pFormatCtx, NULL ) < 0 ) {
        std::cout << "Get Stream Information Error 13" << std::endl;
        avformat_close_input( &pFormatCtx );
        pFormatCtx = NULL;
        return -13;
 }
av_dump_format( pFormatCtx, 0, filenameSrc, 0 );

for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < pFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++ ) {
        if (pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->coder_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            video_stream_index = i;
            break;
        }
 }
```

And I meet the warning at line: `pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->coder_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO`

Warning: `AVCodecContext::coder_type’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/libavcodec/avcodec.h:2815) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]`

I dont understand what does this warning mean and how to resolve it.

Anyone can help me !

Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in your warning message and also you can see in [ffmpeg docs](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.4/deprecated.html) using `AVCodecContext::coder_type` directly is deprecated.

But in docs you can see what else you can do, *use encoder private options instead*.

You create your `AVCodecContext` base on some `AVCodec`. Then you can just use `AVCodec::type`. Or you can get it again from `AVCodecContext` like this :

```
AVCodec *codec = avcodec_find_encoder(codec_context->codec_id);
int coder_type = codec->type;
```

In your case you can change your code like this :

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < pFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++)
{
    if(avcodec_find_encoder(pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_id)->type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
    {
        video_stream_index = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I do the same but it still warn that at line: AVCodec *codec = avcodec_find_encoder(pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_id);

Comment: I am a newbie, can you explain to me what does "deprecated warning" mean ?

Comment: @TrầnQuốcViệt deprecated warning means this usage of code is not recommended in the version you are using, this might (more likely might not) cause trouble in newer versions. What version of ffmpeg you are using? because I'm pretty sure I tasted this code on mine and doesn't have this warning, this should be newer versions issue.

Comment: When I check the header files from my project (avformat.h ...), I see ffmpeg ver 2.1, but from the terminal I see ffmpeg ver 3.3.3.

I use ubuntu 14.4

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `codec_type` from `codecpar`:

```
if (pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
        video_stream_index = i;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please disable Visual Studio's SDL checks.

In Project / Properties / C/C++ / General / SDL checks,
change from **Yes(/sdl)** to **No(/sdl-)**.

This is tested in Visual Studio 2017.